# AngularJS custom directives and webcomponents are Same?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer, web-component

I have working on angularJS for quite some time and able to understand to an extent, Now I like to know the emerging webcomponents (http://webcomponents.org/ ) lets say polymer (https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/), X-tags (http://www.x-tags.org/) or many others are similar to that of AngularJS directive behavior.

Ex:

```
myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);

myapp.directive('element', function() {
    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'E'; /* restrict this directive to elements */

    directive.template = "My first directive: {{textToInsert}}";

    return directive;
});
```

In HTML

```
<element></element>
```

Now the Polymer example

HTML:

```
<element></paper-tabs>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  var tabs = document.querySelector('element');

  tabs.addEventListener('core-select', function() {
    console.log("Selected: " + tabs.selected);
  });
</script>
```

My Question is: If my understanding is correct (Angular Directives are similar to polymers), If so, There is no point to use webcomponents in my app, when I chose AngularJS as my core framework to create apps.

Comment: I got my clarification from here 
http://www.binpress.com/blog/2014/06/26/polymer-vs-angular/ . Keeping this question open, so that guys here can take advantage of this answer

Answer (score 0):

Angular Directives and Web-Components are **NOT** the same.

All Angular Directives are compiled to regular HTML when a page loads up in the browsers by Angular.

Where as Web Components are actual custom-elements that make use of ShadowDOM and few other Specifications which Angular knows nothing about.

Polymer is a library that Sugar-coats Web-Components API.

Both of these Technologies Full Fill very much the same needs and it is up to choice to use one of these Frameworks.